# Enable CORS for Chrome Extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension, request, cors, fetch

I use Fetch API (Javascript) in a Chrome Extension to retrieve a .json from my server.
The request can't be submitted due to [Chrome CORS - Preflight Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OQzS3.png) <- Error Screenshot

How can I enable CORS when my client is a Chrome Extension?

Comment: You need to configure your server to accept CORS calls by defining which origins and which HTTP methods are allowed. See also this post: https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/11089651?hl=en

Answer (score 2):

You need to request the [cross-origin permission](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/xhr#requesting-permission) for your server's host.
Add your server's host to your `manifest.json` permissions field:

```
{
  "name": "...",
  ...
  "permissions": [
    ...,
    "https://yourserver.com/"
  ],
  ...
}
```

You can add multiple hosts in `permissions` field, so you can enable cross-origin permission for all the hosts you need.

Comment: This is only valid for MV2. See `host_permissions` for MV3.